# Google Apps Script: Function to update names from one sheet to another times out. Please refine my loops

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an app through google docs that I use to record student attendance to my after school tutoring center. I have had higher than usual attendance and my code is not efficient enough to run before timing out. Please assist me in editing my code so that it runs more effectively.

I have to note that I am an absolute beginner, so if this is inappropriately posted, please give me constructive feedback on how to get help with this problem. And I apologize in advance for the (I assume) horrible code you are about to see - it's the best I could do and I worked very hard to create this.

Thank you.

Code:

```
function updateAttendance(){
  var itemSpreadsheetKey = '';
  var openedSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(itemSpreadsheetKey);
  var sheetStudentNames = openedSS.getSheetByName("StudentNames");
  var sheetDailyData = openedSS.getSheetByName("DailyData");
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(itemSpreadsheetKey);
  var dailyDataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DailyData");
  var studentNameSheet = ss.getSheetByName("StudentNames");
  var dailyData = dailyDataSheet.getDataRange();
  var studentNames = studentNameSheet.getDataRange();
  var dailyLastRow = dailyData.getLastRow();
  var studentNamesLastRow = studentNames.getLastRow();
  var studentNamesLastColumn = studentNames.getLastColumn();
  var dailyDataNamesArray = sheetDailyData.getRange(2, 1, dailyLastRow).getValues();

  for (var i=1; i<=dailyDataNamesArray.length; i++) {
    if (i != ""){
      var dailyTime = dailyData.getCell(i, 5).getValue();
      for (var j=2; j<=studentNamesLastRow; j++) {
        var today = dailyData.getCell(1, 8).getValue();
        if (dailyData.getCell(i, 1).getValue() == studentNames.getCell(j, 1).getValue())     {
          studentNames.getCell(1, studentNamesLastColumn).offset(0, 1).setValue(today);
          studentNames.getCell(j, studentNamesLastColumn).offset(0, 1).setValue(dailyTime);
        } 
      }
    }
  }  
  return app;
}
```

Comment: Change or hide your spreadsheet key to prevent possible vandalism - there are some seriously antisocial people out there.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your script to go faster you must  use array manipulation instead of all these range.setValue() .

Change all the values in a global array (a pair of actually) and when you're done just write these arrays to their respective sheets.

The difference will be enormous ! believe me ;)

All this is pretty well explained in the [documentation about best practices.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices#batchOperations)

Here is a "translation" of your code, I'm not sure I didn't make any error in transposition but I have no way to check without knowing what is in your sheets.

Just remember that arrays are 0 indexed while ranges start at 1.

```
function updateAttendance(){
  var itemSpreadsheetKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
  var openedSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(itemSpreadsheetKey);
  var sheetStudentNames = openedSS.getSheetByName("StudentNames");
  var sheetDailyData = openedSS.getSheetByName("DailyData");
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(itemSpreadsheetKey);
  var dailyDataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DailyData");
  var studentNameSheet = ss.getSheetByName("StudentNames");
  var dailyData = dailyDataSheet.getDataRange();
  var studentNames = studentNameSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var dailyLastRow = dailyData.getLastRow();
  var studentNamesLastRow = studentNames.getLastRow();
  var studentNamesLastColumn = studentNames.getLastColumn();
  var dailyDataNamesArray = sheetDailyData.getDataRange().getValues();

  for (var i = 1 ; i < dailyDataNamesArray.length; i++) {
    if (i != ""){
      var dailyTime = dailyDataNamesArray[i][4];
      for (var j=1; j<studentNamesLastRow; j++) {
        var today = dailyDataNamesArray[0][7];
        if (dailyDataNamesArray[i][0] == studentNames[i][0])     {
          studentNames[0][studentNamesLastColumn+1] = today;
          studentNames[j][studentNamesLastColumn+1] = dailyTime;
        } 
      }
    }
  }  
  studentNameSheet.getRange(1,1,studentNames.length,studentNames[0].length).setValues(studentNames):  
  dailyDataSheet.getRange(1,1,dailyDataNamesArray.length,dailyDataNamesArray[0].length).setValues(dailyDataNamesArray):  
  return app;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your input - this could work, though I'm getting an "undefined" error on this line of code:

     if (dailyDataNamesArray[i][0] == studentNames[i][0])    

I believe it is saying that the "studentNames portion is undefined, but I'm not sure. As I said - truly a beginner.

Comment: it seems I made an error, should it be if (dailyDataNamesArray[i][0] == studentNames[j][0]) instead ?  as I said, without knowing your date the translation isn't easy. use Logger.log at some places to check data in the script.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the code after the `var dailyDataNamesArray` line with the following.  It's a bit of a guess, so I hope for you that it works:

```
var todayCell1 = studentNames.getCell(1, studentNamesLastColumn).offset(0, 1);
for (var i=1; i<=dailyDataNamesArray.length; i++) {
  if (i != ""){
    var dailyTime = dailyData.getCell(i, 5).getValue();
    var dailyVar2 = dailyData.getCell(i, 1).getValue();
    for (var j=2; j<=studentNamesLastRow; j++) {
      var today = dailyData.getCell(1, 8).getValue();
      if ( dailyVar2 == studentNames.getCell(j, 1).getValue()) {
        todayCell1.setValue(today);
        studentNames.getCell(j, studentNamesLastColumn).offset(0, 1).setValue(dailyTime);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This wont make a difference. Needs to use array versions like get/setValues